# How to specify content type as application/json while sending message to azure service bus queue in node js?

Tags: node.js, azure, azureservicebus, azure-queues

I am sending message to queue using `@azure/service-bus` package and `sendMessages` function as mentioned in [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-nodejs-how-to-use-queues).
When I am sending a javascript array `[{ name: "Albert Einstein", "company": "xyz" }]` it is giving an error `TypeError: Provided value for 'message' must be of type ServiceBusMessage`. So after research found out it adds **body** key e.g. `[body:{name: "Albert Einstein", "company": "xyz"}]`. But this inserts record with content-type as application/xml. Is there any way I can specify content-type:application/json?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify `contentType` like below:

```
const messages = [
    {
        body: { "name": "Albert Einstein", "company": "xyz"},
        contentType: "application/json"
    }
]
```

Please refer to [ServiceBusMessage](http://ServiceBusMessage):

[image]