# TypeError: Provided value for 'message' must be of type: ServiceBusMessage in a Service Bus Queue Azure

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I have the following code that connects a JSON file with an Azure Service Bus Trigger but when the trigger is activated I encounter the error `TypeError: Provided value for 'message' must be of type: ServiceBusMessage`. I have found the following link that provides some sort of help but it wasn't that useful [How to specify content type as application/json while sending message to azure service bus queue in node js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66226741/how-to-specify-content-type-as-application-json-while-sending-message-to-azure-s)

```
module.exports = async function (context, myBlob) {
    context.log("JavaScript blob trigger function processed blob \n Blob:", context.bindingData.blobTrigger, "\n Blob Size:", myBlob.length, "Bytes");
    if(context.bindingData.name.indexOf("json_results") == -1){
        context.log(context.bindingData.name);
        return;
    }

const data = JSON.parse(myBlob.toString());
context.log(data);

// service bus queue
const { ServiceBusClient } = require("@azure/service-bus");
// connection string to your Service Bus namespace
const connectionString = "Endpoint=sb://servicebus.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=xxxxx";



const sbClient = new ServiceBusClient(connectionString);

// name of the queue
const queueName = "service-bus-queue";
context.log("Creating queue: ", queueName);

const sender = sbClient.createSender(queueName)


try{
    // Tries to send all messages in a single batch.
    // Will fail if the messages cannot fit in a batch.
    // await sender.sendMessages(messages);
    let batch = await sender.createMessageBatch();
    for (let index=0; index < data.length; index++){
        // for each message in the array            
        // try to add the message to the batch
        if (!batch.tryAddMessage(data[index])) {            
            // if it fails to add the message to the current batch
            // send the current batch as it is full
            await sender.sendMessages(batch);

            // then, create a new batch 
            batch = await sender.createMessageBatch();

            // now, add the message failed to be added to the previous batch to this batch
            if (!batch.tryAddMessage(data[index])) {
                // if it still can't be added to the batch, the message is probably too big to fit in a batch
                throw new Error("Message too big to fit in a batch");
            }
        }
    }
    // Send the last created batch of messages to the queue
    await sender.sendMessages(batch);

    context.log(`Sent a batch of messages to the queue: ${queueName}`);

    // Close the sender
    await sender.close();
} finally {
    await sbClient.close();
}

};
```

How do I convert this JSON file properly so it can be sent correctly to the Service Bus?

This is some sample data from the JSON file:

```
[
    {
    "Id": "MCMID|10091810600907894473354109933466533357",
    "FC_rev": 0.0,
    "FC_seg": 0.0,
    "MC_rev": 0.0,
    "MC_seg": 0.0,
    "PC_rev": 0.0,
    "PC_seg": 0.0,
    "PNR_booking": 0,
    "SP_ID_f": "1009181060090789447335410993346653335721632922568DCABOI",
    "Saver_rev": 439.08,
    "Saver_seg": 8.0,
    "Total_seg": 8.0,
    "num_PAX": 2,
    "EndUserID": "oeu1632860659758r0.8453951976577427",
    "purchase_time_": "00000000000000"
},
{
    "Id": "MCMID|1015698875809402563583619705251328622",
    "FC_rev": 0.0,
    "FC_seg": 0.0,
    "MC_rev": 160.0,
    "MC_seg": 2.0,
    "PC_rev": 0.0,
    "PC_seg": 0.0,
    "PNR_booking": 0,
    "SP_ID_f": "101569887580940256358361970525132862211632922598LAXZLO",
    "Saver_rev": 0.0,
    "Saver_seg": 0.0,
    "Total_seg": 2.0,
    "num_PAX": 1,
    "EndUserID": "oeu1632922592097r0.5015812337790303",
    "purchase_time_": "00000000000000"
},
{
    "Id": "MCMID|1015698875809402563583619705251328622",
    "FC_rev": 150.08369127516778,
    "FC_seg": 1.0,
    "MC_rev": 99.77630872483222,
    "MC_seg": 1.0,
    "PC_rev": 0.0,
    "PC_seg": 0.0,
    "PNR_booking": 0,
    "SP_ID_f": "101569887580940256358361970525132862211632922598PDXLAX",
    "Saver_rev": 0.0,
    "Saver_seg": 0.0,
    "Total_seg": 2.0,
    "num_PAX": 1,
    "EndUserID": "oeu1632922592097r0.5015812337790303",
    "purchase_time_": "00000000000000"
    }
]
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include a sample message that you're trying to save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming each element in `data` array is a JSON object, what you would need to do is convert that object into a string and then create a new JSON object for your message.

Try to change the following line of code:

```
if (!batch.tryAddMessage(data[index])) {
```

to

```
const messageBody = JSON.stringify(data[index]);
if (!batch.tryAddMessage({body: messageBody})) {
```

**UPDATE**

This is the code I tried:

```
const { ServiceBusClient } = require("@azure/service-bus");
const connectionString = "Endpoint=sb://account.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=key";
const queueName = "queue-name";

const data = [
    {
    "Id": "MCMID|10091810600907894473354109933466533357",
    "FC_rev": 0.0,
    "FC_seg": 0.0,
    "MC_rev": 0.0,
    "MC_seg": 0.0,
    "PC_rev": 0.0,
    "PC_seg": 0.0,
    "PNR_booking": 0,
    "SP_ID_f": "1009181060090789447335410993346653335721632922568DCABOI",
    "Saver_rev": 439.08,
    "Saver_seg": 8.0,
    "Total_seg": 8.0,
    "num_PAX": 2,
    "EndUserID": "oeu1632860659758r0.8453951976577427",
    "purchase_time_": "00000000000000"
},
{
    "Id": "MCMID|1015698875809402563583619705251328622",
    "FC_rev": 0.0,
    "FC_seg": 0.0,
    "MC_rev": 160.0,
    "MC_seg": 2.0,
    "PC_rev": 0.0,
    "PC_seg": 0.0,
    "PNR_booking": 0,
    "SP_ID_f": "101569887580940256358361970525132862211632922598LAXZLO",
    "Saver_rev": 0.0,
    "Saver_seg": 0.0,
    "Total_seg": 2.0,
    "num_PAX": 1,
    "EndUserID": "oeu1632922592097r0.5015812337790303",
    "purchase_time_": "00000000000000"
},
{
    "Id": "MCMID|1015698875809402563583619705251328622",
    "FC_rev": 150.08369127516778,
    "FC_seg": 1.0,
    "MC_rev": 99.77630872483222,
    "MC_seg": 1.0,
    "PC_rev": 0.0,
    "PC_seg": 0.0,
    "PNR_booking": 0,
    "SP_ID_f": "101569887580940256358361970525132862211632922598PDXLAX",
    "Saver_rev": 0.0,
    "Saver_seg": 0.0,
    "Total_seg": 2.0,
    "num_PAX": 1,
    "EndUserID": "oeu1632922592097r0.5015812337790303",
    "purchase_time_": "00000000000000"
    }
];

const sbClient = new ServiceBusClient(connectionString);
console.log(sbClient);
console.log('===================');
const sender = sbClient.createSender(queueName);
console.log(sender);
console.log('===================');

async function sendMessages() {
  let batch = await sender.createMessageBatch();
  for (let index=0; index<data.length; index++) {
    const message = {
      body: JSON.stringify(data[index])
    };
    console.log(message);
    console.log('===================');
    if (!batch.tryAddMessage(message)) {
        // if it fails to add the message to the current batch
        // send the current batch as it is full
        await sender.sendMessages(batch);
        console.log('message batch sent...');
        // then, create a new batch
        batch = await sender.createMessageBatch();

        // now, add the message failed to be added to the previous batch to this batch
        if (!batch.tryAddMessage(message)) {
            // if it still can't be added to the batch, the message is probably too big to fit in a batch
            throw new Error("Message too big to fit in a batch");
        }
    }
  }
  if (batch.count > 0) {
    await sender.sendMessages(batch);
    console.log('message batch sent...');
  }
}

sendMessages().catch((err) => {
  console.error("The sample encountered an error:", err);
});
```

Comment: It didn't work, I still get the same error. I heard about installing an SDK but I am unsure if there's one for this request

Comment: As mentioned in my comment, can you share some sample data? I don’t think it’s an issue with the SDK.

Comment: I have added some sample data for debugging purposes

Comment: Can you let me know if this is enough or if you require additional records? Please let me know.

Comment: I just tried your code with my changes and I was able to send the messages successfully. I wrote a console application though.

Comment: Updated my answer with the code I wrote. HTH.

Answer (score 1):

For me, fix was to pass body as field

```
const messages = [
  { body: { ...object} },
];
```